# Acessar web service com python e converter XML em JSON e armazenar em variáveis os valores do JSON

Tags: python

```
       headers = {"": ""}

       PARAMS = { "": "", "dataInicial": "", "dataFinal": "", "": "",
              "": ""}

       # Requisitando ao URL
       response = requests.post(url="https://",
                             headers=headers, data=PARAMS)

       # Armazenando o resultado da requisição
       result = response.text
    
       # Convertendo XML em JSON
       dicionario = xmltodict.parse(result)
       dados = json.dumps(dicionario, indent = 4)
```

Estou tentando acessar um WEB Service disponibilizado por outra empresa e está vindo no formato XML, eu preciso pegar esses dados e inserir no banco de dados... Segue o código que estou me baseando (não coloquei os dados do reais do web Service por conta dos direitos da empresa) mas não está dando muito certo... Pensei em quem sabe transformar em JSON e depois acessar os dados e inserir no banco.
Procurei em inúmeros lugares na internet e achei pouquíssima coisa sobre.
Quem puder me ajudar vai me quebrar um galhão!

Answer (score -1):

Não há um único jeito de fazer isso, mas uma maneira é usar a biblioteca xml.etree.ElementTree do Python. Vc tem que dar mais detalhe com o tipo de XML e qual banco de dados vc vai usar para inserir essas informações.